# Monitoring dynamics CRM stringmap table update using plugin --- StringMap as PrimaryEntity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

In dynamics CRM, can I monitor stringmap table update using plugin? I only need to monitor one attribute, like [AttributeName]='abc'

I added the following item into the plugin XML configure file, after I import the XML file, the PrimaryEntity is none.

```
<Step PluginTypeName="Classes.Ind" Description="Ind PreCreate" InvocationSource="0" MessageName="Create" Mode="0" PrimaryEntityName="stringmap" SecondaryEntityName="none" Stage="10" SupportedDeployment="0" Rank="1" Id="B53A4743-*">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamics CRM plugin, cannot register StringMap as PrimaryEntity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524962/dynamics-crm-plugin-cannot-register-stringmap-as-primaryentity)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to tap into customizations is by listening to the Publish or PublishAll messages. 
In your plug-in you’ll need to process the customizations xml (XmlDocument) for specific changes.

e.g.

```
<importexportxml>
 <optionsets>
  <optionset>new_myoptionset</optionset>
 </optionsets>
</importexportxml>
```

When you register a plug-in on the Publish or PublishAll Messages the context.InputParameters keys correspond to the publish request public properties.

In your case you need to read the ParameterXml Into an XmlDocument and search for your optionset changes.

This might look like the following :

```
if (context.Message == "Publish"" && context.InputParameters.Contains("ParameterXml"))
{ 
     XmlDocument xCust = new XmlDocument();
     xCust.Load(context.InputParameters["ParameterXml"].ToString());

     // look for your optionset using xpath   …
}
```

Comment: context.InputParameters["ParameterXml"].ToString()) looks like <publish xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/WebServices">
<entities><entity>CustomEntity</entity></entities></publish> It is wired that this returned xml is not following the ParameterXml schema...