# Dynamics CRM plugin, cannot register StringMap as PrimaryEntity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

In dynamics CRM, can I monitor stringmap table update using plugin? I only need to monitor one attribute, like [AttributeName]='abc'

I added the following item into the plugin XML configure file, after I import the XML file, the PrimaryEntity is none.

```
<Step PluginTypeName="Classes.Ind" Description="Ind PreCreate" InvocationSource="0" MessageName="Create" Mode="0" PrimaryEntityName="stringmap" SecondaryEntityName="none" Stage="10" SupportedDeployment="0" Rank="1" Id="B53A4743-*">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `Message-entity support for plug-ins.xlsx` file from SDK, the only message supported for `StringMap` entity is `RetrieveMultiple`

Comment: thank you for the answer, and I still cannot find the way to plugin my code into the stringmap (optionset) update pipeline.